# n-gram generation for words of non english languages

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters, n-gram, non-english

I am performing Bigram generation for words of Czech Language. I am able to generate Bi-grams using Python. The problem is with non English characters in Czech language.

Input:

**republikán strategii proti znovuzvolení Obamy**.

Performing Bigram ,the output is

**[['republik\xc3\xa1n', 'strategii'], ['strategii', 'proti'], ['proti', 'znovuzvolen\xc3\xad'], ['znovuzvolen\xc3\xad', 'Obamy']]**

The special letters of Czech language is converted as \xc3\xad in bigram.
What changes needs should be done with code to get the special letters in proper way in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is correct, but when you convert a list to a string, the output is prepared using `repr` for the list items, not `str`. Compare:

```
>>> x = [['republikán']]
>>> print(x)
[['republik\xc3\xa1n']]
>>> print(x[0])
['republik\xc3\xa1n']
>>> print(x[0][0])
republikán
>>>
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine but I want it to print all the words in the list and not just the first word.

Comment: The ability to print a list is intended as a debugging tool, not for final output. Build the string you want from the list elements, then print that.